# Disabling checkboxes in a group when 1 of the group is selected using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of checkboxes which are grouped by a priority number and I want a way that a user can select multiple ones from different priority groups but only one from each

```
<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='priority[]'  />first choice in priority 1 group<br>
<input type='checkbox' value='2' name='priority[]'  /> second choice in priority 1 group <br>
<input type='checkbox' value='3' name='priority[]'  /> third choice in priority 1 group <br>
<input type='checkbox' value='4' name='priority[]'  /> first choice in priority 2 group <br>
<input type='checkbox' value='5' name='priority[]'  /> second choice in priority 2 group <br>
<input type='checkbox' value='6' name='priority[]'  /> third choice in priority 2 group <br>
```

So in the example above it would fine for a user to select 1 and 5 as they are in different priority groups, but not 1 and 2 as they are in the same priority group

So I’ve been thinking of using javascript to disable the other checkboxes in the group when one is checked, so for example if I select 1, then 2 and 3 would be disabled but not 4, 5 or 6

I’ve been looking to see if there is anything in jQuery’s library but can’t see anything, I was wondering if I could group the checkboxes together using id or tabindex and then do a disable that way but no luck so far
The checkboxes are dynamically generated from a database table so I can play around with sorting them or adding divs around them if needed
Can anyone help?

Cheers

Mike

Comment: Isn't this what radio buttons are for?

Comment: I had a small chill when I saw the name attributes with brackets in them. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** What about this:

```
$('.check').change(function() {
    var group = $(this).data('priority');
    $('.check[data-priority="' + group + '"]').not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
})​;
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/Qvhxp/1/

**2.**
You would better use radio buttons instead of checkboxes (apply -webkit-appearance, -moz-appearance, if needed).

Comment: thats perfect thanks very much, will look at using radio buttons as well though